# Bootstrap not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I think I installed Bootstrap correctly. I downloaded the files and put the js and css files in a directory labeled "bootstrap" in my root directory. Then I put this code in my project expecting it to look like a Twitter Bootstrap 3 button but it didn't work:

```
<a href="#add_form" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Create</a>
```

did I install Bootstrap wrong? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you referencing the bootstrap files?  If you aren't, I'd take a strong look at some HTML and CSS 101 tutorials before going into frameworks.

Comment: how do I reference them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the references to the css

```
<link href="/yourBootstrapDirectoryPath/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Is there a way to reference this in a php file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP but try searching for "referencing CSS file in PHP".